# Spring Integration Channeling With Bean Name vs Method Name

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-dsl

I have PublishSubscribeChannel like this:

```
@Bean(name = {"publishCha.input", "publishCha2.input"}) //2 subscribers
    public MessageChannel publishAction() {
        PublishSubscribeChannel ps = MessageChannels.publishSubscribe().get();
        ps.setMaxSubscribers(8);
        return ps;
    }
```

I have also subscriber channels:

```
@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow publishCha() {
        return f -> f
                .handle(m -> System.out.println("In publishCha channel..."));
    }


@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow publishCha2() {
        return f -> f
                .handle(m -> System.out.println("In publishCha2 channel..."));
    }
```

And finally another subscriber:

```
@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow anotherChannel() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("publishAction")
                .handle(m -> System.out.println("ANOTHER CHANNEL IS HERE!"))
                .get();
    }
```

The problem is, when I call channel with method name "publishAction" like below from another flow, it only prints "ANOTHER CHANNEL HERE" and ignores other subscribers. However, if I call with 
`.channel("publishCha.input")`, this time it enters publishCha and publishCha2 subscribers but ignoring the third subscriber.

```
@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow flow() { 
        return f -> f
       .channel("publishAction");
    }
```

My question is, why those two different channeling methods yields different results?

```
.channel("publishAction") // channeling with method name executes third subscriber

.channel("publishCha.input") // channelling with bean name, executes first and second subscribers
```

Edit: narayan-sambireddy requested how I send messages to channel. I send it via Gateway:

```
@MessagingGateway
public interface ExampleGateway {

@Gateway(requestChannel = "flow.input")
    void flow(Order orders);
}
```

In Main:

```
Order order = new Order();
      order.addItem("PC", "TTEL", 2000, 1)
    ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Start.class, args);
    ctx.getBean(ExampleGateway.class).flow(order);
```

Comment: Could you also post how are you sending messages to these channels -- wanted to check how you are referring these channels ( either beanName or methodName ) while sending messages.

Comment: @narayan-sambireddy I added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem with the third subscriber that you miss the purpose of the `name` in the `@Bean`:

```
/**
 * The name of this bean, or if several names, a primary bean name plus aliases.
 * <p>If left unspecified, the name of the bean is the name of the annotated method.
 * If specified, the method name is ignored.
 * <p>The bean name and aliases may also be configured via the {@link #value}
 * attribute if no other attributes are declared.
 * @see #value
 */
@AliasFor("value")
String[] name() default {};
```

So, method name as a bean name is ignored in this case, therefore Spring Integration Java DSL doesn't find a bean with the `publishAction` and creates one - `DirectChannel`.

You can use *method reference* though:

```
IntegrationFlows.from(publishAction())
```

Or, if that is in a different configuration class, you can re-use one of the predefined name"

```
 IntegrationFlows.from(publishCha.input)
```

This way DSL will re-use existing bean and will just add one more subscriber to that pub-sub channel.

Comment: Thanks for spending your time for explaining.